# Changes don't commit after RFC of ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI

Tags: abap

I'm calling `ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI` with an RFC. The purchase info records get a new number, but the changes aren't commited to the db.

The commit is supposed to be implicit after a RFC, but it isn't. I've tried adding an explicit `COMMIT WORK` after the function call, but this didn't help.

The changes are commited properly if I use a regular function call (not remote), however performance is very slow.

Please help.

```
FORM CALL_BAPI_PIR.
  lv_taskname = |PIR-{ lv_sentjobs WIDTH = 3 ALIGN = RIGHT PAD = '0' }|.

    CALL FUNCTION 'ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI'
     STARTING NEW TASK lv_taskname
     DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
     PERFORMING RETURN_BAPI_PIR ON END OF TASK
      EXPORTING
        testrun          = p_test
      TABLES
        t_eina           = GT_ME_EINA
        t_einax          = GT_ME_EINAX
        t_eine           = GT_ME_EINE
        t_einex          = GT_ME_EINEX
        return           = GT_ME_INFORECORD_RETURN
       EXCEPTIONS
         system_failure        = 1 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
         communication_failure = 2 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
         resource_failure      = 3
     .
     CASE sy-subrc.
       WHEN 0.
         lv_sentjobs = lv_sentjobs + 1.
         COMMIT WORK.
       WHEN 1 OR 2.
         MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg TYPE 'I'.
         WRITE: / lv_taskname, ':', lv_exceptionmsg.
     ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.

FORM RETURN_BAPI_PIR USING TASKNAME.
  DATA INFO LIKE RFCSI.
  RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION 'ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI'
    IMPORTING
      RFCSI_EXPORT = INFO
      RETURN = GT_ME_INFORECORD_RETURN.
  lv_recvjobs = lv_recvjobs + 1.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Sorry but you don't commit in the process you start but instead you do it in the current LUW which does not know anything about the LUW started by `STARTING NEW TASK`.

Comment: How can I commit in the remote process and why is the implicit commit not happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by making a wrapper function that ends with a commit, and calling the wrapper function instead of the standard function.

```
FUNCTION z_inforecord_maintain_mult2
  IMPORTING
    VALUE(testrun) TYPE bapiflag-bapiflag OPTIONAL
  EXPORTING
    VALUE(et_eina) TYPE mewieina_mig_t
    VALUE(et_eine) TYPE mewieine_t
  TABLES
    t_eina TYPE mewieina_mig_t OPTIONAL
    t_einax TYPE mewieinax_t OPTIONAL
    t_eine TYPE mewieine_t OPTIONAL
    t_einex TYPE mewieinex_t OPTIONAL
    txt_lines TYPE mewipirtext_tt OPTIONAL
    cond_validity TYPE mewivalidity_tt OPTIONAL
    condition TYPE mewicondition_tt OPTIONAL
    cond_scale_value TYPE mewiscaleval_tt OPTIONAL
    cond_scale_quan TYPE mewiscalequan_tt OPTIONAL
    return TYPE fs4mig_t_bapiret2 OPTIONAL.



  CALL FUNCTION 'ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI'
    EXPORTING
      testrun          = testrun
    IMPORTING
      et_eina          = et_eina
      et_eine          = et_eine
    TABLES
      t_eina           = t_eina
      t_einax          = t_einax
      t_eine           = t_eine
      t_einex          = t_einex
      txt_lines        = txt_lines
      cond_validity    = cond_validity
      condition        = condition
      cond_scale_value = cond_scale_value
      cond_scale_quan  = cond_scale_quan
      return           = return
    .
  IF SY-subrc = 0.
    COMMIT WORK.
  ENDIF.
ENDFUNCTION.
```

Answer (score 1):

With RFC, there's an implicit database commit at some point of time in the **calling program**, but not in the RFC session, like there's no implicit database commit after `SUBMIT`.

You may chain several function module calls in the same RFC session, and to chain a SAP LUW commit in the RFC session you may call the function module `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` to do a `COMMIT WORK`. The solution then depends on the type of RFC you use.

In your case, you use asynchronous RFC with a callback i.e. with wait, so the solution will be to

- indicate `KEEPING TASK` at `RECEIVE RESULTS` so that to keep the RFC session open after calling `ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI`
- use `WAIT FOR ASYNCHRONOUS TASKS` so that `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` is called sequentially after `ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI` has ended.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI'
       STARTING NEW TASK lv_taskname
       DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
       PERFORMING RETURN_BAPI_PIR ON END OF TASK
...
       EXCEPTIONS
         system_failure        = 1 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
         communication_failure = 2 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
         resource_failure      = 3.
IF sy-subrc = 0.

  WAIT FOR ASYNCHRONOUS TASKS UNTIL lv_recvjobs = lv_sentjobs.

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
        STARTING NEW TASK lv_taskname " <====== reuse existing RFC session/closed implicitly right after
        DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
        EXCEPTIONS
          system_failure        = 1 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
          communication_failure = 2 MESSAGE lv_exceptionmsg
          resource_failure      = 3.
...
FORM RETURN_BAPI_PIR USING TASKNAME.
  DATA INFO LIKE RFCSI.
  RECEIVE RESULTS FROM FUNCTION 'ME_INFORECORD_MAINTAIN_MULTI'
    KEEPING TASK " <============== add this to not close the RFC session
    IMPORTING
      RFCSI_EXPORT = INFO
      RETURN = GT_ME_INFORECORD_RETURN.
  lv_recvjobs = lv_recvjobs + 1.
ENDFORM.
```

NB:

- I did not handle the exceptions to simplify the demonstration.
- If you run the RFC under several task names, several RFC sessions are started, so you must call `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` in each of these RFC sesssions.